# Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'

Tags: alamofire

Here is the original github [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/441), support sugested to open a thread here for more public support.

I'm using xcode 6.4.

```
$ pod --version
0.38.2
```

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Turnt' do
    pod 'Starscream'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
end
```

Answer (score 37):

I met similar problem, too. I couldn't figure out why and soon I lost patience so just ignored the error and clicked "run" directly. The error actually disappeared and "Build Succeeded" was shown!

Comment: yes but it comes back when i try to archive the project

Answer (score 9):

There are a few other things you can try:

### Verify xcodebuild version

Make sure your `xcodebuild` version also set to `6.4`.

[image: xcodebuild settings]

### Clean All

You certainly want to try `clean all` in the project. Sometimes that will reset the issue.

### Wipe DerivedData and Xcode Cache

Another thing that could be causing the problem is that you may need to wipe your `DerivedData` folder along with your Xcode cache.

```
echo "Removing DerivedData and Xcode Cache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Give those a whirl and I'll update my answer accordingly. Best of luck!

Comment: `xcodebuild` is set correctly, removing derived data and Cache didn't do anything. Strange thing is, I can run the project, and build it, but if I run the app it just hangs when Alamofire should be used without any errors or debug msgs.

Comment: i only have the option xcode 7.0.1 in there. what to do?

Comment: @Esq leave it at 7.0.1 and follow the rest of the instructions.

Comment: Be careful using rm -rf. If you run that command as root, and the previous cd fails for any reason (e.g. folder doesn't exist), you could inadvertently wipe a lot more than you meant to

Answer (score 7):

I met the same question and by
Product->clean then Product->build fixed it

Comment: This solution worked for me. (I'm using Xcode 9.2 with Swift 4.0)

Answer (score 5):

The fix for me was changing the platform version in my `Podfile` to the same version I was building for in Xcode.  Then run `pod install` again.  Derp.

Example: `platform :ios, '11.2'`

Comment: Derp indeed. Such an obvious solution. Thanks! Both Xcode and Podfile iOS versions have to match. Changing it in either place should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

For me, none of the above answers worked.
Something I did terribly wrong was setting a flag in Other Swift Flags in the Build Settings. **Which override cocoapods custom flags.** 
It shows an error something like this in that case.
Pod installation complete! There are 16 dependencies from the Podfile and 29 total pods installed.

```
[!] The `***** [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` build setting defined in
    `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MishiPay/Pods-MishiPay.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead 
    to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

So Instead of removing my other custom flags. I added one more flag `$(inherited)` after this everything worked fine.

[image]

`$(inherited)` inherits all the custom flags defined by `cocoapods`

Answer (score 1):

This issue was already reported on Github: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/441

Follow the following steps

1. Product -> Clean
2. Restart Xcode
3. Rebuild the project
4. Might have allowed permission to access the keychain

Good Luck and Happy Coding

Comment: "Here is the original github issue, support sugested to open a thread here for more public support."

Comment: Build the project and restart XCode worked to me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's a Xcode bug with Alamofire. Just keep rebuilding the app and cleaning it. After that restart, Xcode and the problem should go away. 
Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forget to add dependency for all targets. I got the issue only while Unit testing, later I recognised that I missed to add it in .pod file for test target.

target 'SujanTests' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.7'

end